# Which is used to answer and accepted in everyday speech? Short answer or in whole sentence

Tags: responses

1. Do you get much homework every day? Yes, I do.
2. Do you get much homework every day? Yes, I get a lot of.

Is it usual to answer in a whole sentence or just use the short answer? Which do you use? Is there any difference between them?
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

*No-one* would say "Yes, I get a lot of."

If you had to answer in a whole sentence (in a language test, for example) it would be "Yes, I [do] get a lot of homework."

"Yes, I do" would be the natural answer in real life. You might also modify it by saying "Yes, quite a lot/rather a lot."